# Refer to iteration number inside for-loop in Stata

Tags: stata

Like many others, I often loop through variables in Stata, running some estimation command and then extracting the results to a variable created to hold them.  This is simple when the variables are numbered sequentially or in some pattern (e.g. even numbers in a set).  As an example:

```
sysuse auto
gen var1 = uniform()
gen var2 = uniform()
gen var3 = uniform()

*Create variables to hold results
gen str4 varname=""
gen results=.

*Loop through three variables
foreach i of numlist 1/3{
    replace varname="var`i'" in `i'
    sum var`i'
    replace results=r(mean) in `i'
}
```

However, I often want to do something similar when the variables are not numeric and/or are not in an easy-to-handle order.  Let's say I wanted to do the same thing for `price`, `mpg`, `weight` and `length` in the auto dataset.  If we set up the for-loop as:

```
sysuse auto
gen str4 varname=""
gen results=.

foreach var of varlist price mpg weight length{
    sum `var'

    *Place values, in order, in rows?
}
```

then we need some way to understand that `price` is the first variable in the list, so its results should go in row 1 (or its name in row 1, or whatever we want to do).

This must be possible, but I would appreciate some suggestions.  A clean/non-hackish way would be ideal, as I will be doing this a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a local counter that you start at 1 and increment at the end of each iteration:

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen varname=""
gen mean=.
local i=1

foreach var of varlist price mpg weight {
     quietly sum `var'
     replace mean = r(mean) in `i'
     replace varname = "`var'" in `i'
     local ++i
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  I didn't know about the ++ option here.

Comment: You can also write it as local i=`i'+1.

Comment: I'm ashamed I never thought of this.  I occasionally use local macros selectively inside loops, but never thought to set i to 1 beforehand and then increment.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this. It's unlikely to seem as direct or simple as the standard technique explained by @Dimitriy V. Masterov, but it has its uses.

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen varname = ""
gen mean = .

local nvars : word count price mpg weight 
tokenize "price mpg weight" 

quietly forval j = 1/`nvars'  {
     sum ``j'', meanonly 
     replace mean = r(mean) in `j'
     replace varname = "``j''" in `j'
}
```

The general points are

1. Words are separated by spaces, except that double quotation marks and compound double quotation marks bind tighter. Thus `a`, `b` and `c` are unsurprisingly the words in `a b c` but there are just two words in `Stata "is great"`
2. You can count how many objects you are looping over. It is the number of words in a string.
3. Applying `tokenize` to an argument string maps the separate words of that argument to local macros named `1`, `2` and so forth. The nested macro references that is likely to imply are interpreted just as you would guess from elementary algebra: the innermost argument is evaluated first.

For more complicated problems, including the unpacking of a varlist, check out also `unab`.